# Pandas DataFrame: Split values in one cell and create into new columns

Tags: pandas, string, split

I'd like to split values(object dtype) by the symbol '|' and create into new columns where have the  each split value.

My intension is to split and use only the first and second one.

i.g.
From:

[image]

To:

[image]

I tried below code and it has error

```
Main = df['Category'].str.split('|').get(0)
Sub = df['Category'].str.split('|').get(1)

df['Main'], df['Sub'] = (Main, Sub)
```

Please share your solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

If I modify your code, you should use `str.get` instead of `get`

```
Main = df['Category'].str.split('|').str.get(0)
Sub = df['Category'].str.split('|').str.get(1)

df['Main'], df['Sub'] = (Main, Sub)
```

However, it would be more convenient to **use expand=True** of the `str.split` function rather than modifying your code.

```
df[['Main', 'Sub']] = df['Category'].str.split('|', expand=True)[[0, 1]]
```

result

df:

```
  Category Main Sub
0  A|B|C|D    A   B
1    A|B|C    A   B
```

---

**Example Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A|B|C|D', 'A|B|C']})
```

Comment: Thanks, It's really helpful! 

By the way, I was trying to extract the last split value as well. 

"df[['Main', 'Sub']] = df['Category'].str.split('|', expand=True)[[0, -1]]"

But it did work. I'm wondering that using "str.get(-1)" is the only way in this case?

Comment: @ShazelP If you want to extract by integer location, you should **use iloc indexer** instead of [] indexer. `df[['Main', 'Sub']] = df['Category'].str.split('|', expand=True).iloc[:, [0, -1]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you just have two columns to extract, an efficient approach would be to use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex:

```
df[['Main', 'Sub']] = df['Category'].str.extract(r'([^|]*)\|([^|]*)')
```

Output:

```
  Category Main Sub
0  A|B|C|D    A   B
1    A|B|C    A   B
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8t6HO1/1)